# not able to see DockLayoutPanel content except header

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt-platform, gwtp

I'm trying to layout my page using DockLayoutPanel and i'm using gwt-platfrom plugin to create presenter and view pairs. when i've added the following code in my view.ui.xml i'm able to see only header part and the rest is not visible, what's wrong in my approach?

```
    <ui:style>        
    .eastPanel {
        background-color: #F60;
    }
    .westPanel {
        background-color: #EEE;
    }
    .northPanel {
        background-color: #39F;
    }
    .southPanel {
        background-color: #99C;
    }
    .centerPanel {
        background-color: #FFC;
    }       
</ui:style>
 <g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
   <g:north size='5'>
     <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.northPanel}">
       <g:Label>This is the NORTH panel</g:Label>
     </g:FlowPanel>
   </g:north>
   <g:west size='15'>
     <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.westPanel}">
       <g:Label>This is the WEST panel</g:Label>
     </g:FlowPanel>
   </g:west>
   <g:center>
     <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.centerPanel}">
       <g:Label>This is the CENTER panel</g:Label>
     </g:FlowPanel>
   </g:center>
 </g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

thanks,

Comment: The width of your west sub-panel is 192em. What's the overall width of the dock layout panel?

Comment: @Boris  i've changed my west size to 15 and tried still it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for not revealing the page there are two mistakes while writing,
1. Use only one Unit(UM/PX/Percent) to structure all the sides of the DockLayoutPanel
2. Since I'm using gwt platform, I need to use 
    RevealRootLayoutContentEvent.fire(this,this); 
in my Presenter's 
    revealInParent() instead of 
    RevealRootContentEvent.fire(this,this);

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change em anywhere, it has a default size of 16px. Therefore, 192 em can easily mean 3,072 px. I don't know how DockLayoutPanel behaves when a zone is bigger than the screen, but I am pretty sure it does not look pretty.

The other possibility is that you need to set a height of DockLayoutPanel, if it does not get it from a parent widget.

Comment: @Andri Volgin  i've changed my west size to 15 and tried still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem before. Just set the height for your center panel. Everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `DockLayoutPanel` into `LayoutPanel`.

```
LayoutPanel panel = new LayoutPanel();
panel.add(Your DockLayoutPanel);
```

Comment: You may some more description so that other can understand.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this. I'm use GWTP:

```
<ui:style>
.eastPanel {
    background-color: #F60;
}

.westPanel {
    background-color: #EEE;
}

.northPanel {
    background-color: #39F;
}

.southPanel {
    background-color: #99C;
}

.centerPanel {
    background-color: #FFC;
}

header {
    background: red;
}
</ui:style>


<g:RootLayoutPanel>
    <g:layer>
        <g:DockLayoutPanel >
            <g:north size='60'>
                <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.northPanel}">
                    <g:Label>This is the WEST panel</g:Label>
                </g:FlowPanel>
            </g:north>
            <g:west size='300'>
                <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.westPanel}">
                    <g:Label>This is the WEST panel</g:Label>
                </g:FlowPanel>
            </g:west>
            <g:center>
                <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.centerPanel}">
                    <g:Label>This is the CENTER panel</g:Label>
                </g:FlowPanel>
            </g:center>
        </g:DockLayoutPanel>
    </g:layer>
</g:RootLayoutPanel>
```